# Deleting Tables Containing a Range of Columns

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am going through several hundred Word documents that contain dozens of tables each.  I need to delete all of the tables that contain more than three columns.  The entire table needs to be removed from the document.  I cannot simply delete all of the tables in the document (a Macro for which I already have) because these documents contain bulleted information in table format.

Alternatively, a Macro for converting tables with three or fewer columns into text would also get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
    Sub RemoveDataTables()
    For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If Table.Columns.Count > 3 Then
    Table.Delete
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```